# window.print() gives no only selected option

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When using print from Google Chrome one can select an option in the dialog to make Chrome only print the contents that is selected. But when I fire

```
window.print()
```

from the console after setting a selection on the page I don't get this option. Is there some way to make this option appear? Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct as far as i'm aware you cant make the dialogue appear, you can however print specific html content, here's an example of how to do so :-

```
    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
      var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

      mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
      mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
      mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
      mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
      mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

      mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
      mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

      mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();

      return true;
    }
```

elem being the HTML container of the content you want to print.

Comment: Your function does not work in my browser. I see some window flashing and disappearing when I removed the mywindow.close(); line it worked but I also need the contents in the head of my document included in the print. I can create a selection in javascript and I can open a print dialog but the option in the dialog does not appear unfortunately so I found another solution that did the trick. But thanks for your answer.